# Javascript: change color of the entire page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, colors, background-color

I'm developing a website for a personal project and I have a problem with the background color setting.

Whatever I do to change the color only changes the color of the container inside my page.
I tried to add a class to my div in App.js or to add background color in the css body property of my App.css but nothing works. I did the same in the public folder in index.html by adding in the body `<body style="background-color: red">` but still the same problem.

I put a part of my frontend code here and screenshot of my issue after, hoping you can help me.

App.js

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import './App.css';

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
    ...
  });

  return (
    <div className='global'> //try to implement a css class with a new background color set
      <div>
        <NavBar />
      </div>
      <div className="container mt-3">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          ....
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

App.css

```
...

.global {
  background-color: red;
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App /> //I also try to implement a css class with a new background color set for app but same issue
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

index.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

[my site before changing color in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W03JL.png)

[my site after changing color in my code with new color only on one part of my page, I scribbled in green the part where the color does not change but I would like it to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQTb4.png)

Comment: Change background-color inside body selector inside your index.css. I hope it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to change the colour of the whole page, you can just target `body` in your CSS, like

```
body{
  background-color: red;
}
```

You can make this change in your `index.css` and add this line in your body selector.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

---

<kbd>IMPORTANT NOTE</kbd>

There may be a case where you have elements with their own background colour, and they will continue to have that until to specifically change each element CSS. Changing `body` or `html` background colour won't impact individual elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help, while rereading my code I realized that I had already defined the body tag in another css file with another color. By deleting this block everything works normally :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you already tried adding CSS directly to `body`, and it doesn't work even then, then most probably there could be some CSS that's causing the `body` to not occupy the full width and height of the page.

Inspect the `body` element in your web page in a web browser and check if it covers the whole window or not..

Can't give any more accurate suggestions without looking at the generated HTML/CSS code or a URL Of the web page that you're working on.

Comment: Thanks for your help, while rereading my code I realized that I had already defined the body tag in another css file with another color. By deleting this block everything works normally :)

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that the whole page is affected by the color change, you could try to target the `html` tag directly in a css file:

```
html {
  background-color: red;
}
```